# How to deal with SQL IN Operator returning multiple values when only one is needed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child

I am working on a multiple parent child hierarchy that looks something like this. This is a subset of a table with 105k records.

| NodeKey | ParentKey | Child | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | A |  |
| 2 |  | B |  |
| 3 |  | C | A |
| 4 |  | D | B |
| 5 |  | D | C |

I need to fill the column ParentKey with data with the following condition.

If the value in Parent is `NULL`, set the value in ParentKey `NULL` as well.

If the value in Parent is `NOT NULL` and is also in Child, then select the corresponding NodeKey and set it as the value in ParentKey (see 2nd table).

I can do that but there is a problem when the value from the Parent column appears more than once in the Child column.

In the 5th row it doesn't matter which value is chosen between 3 or 4. It can be either one.

| NodeKey | ParentKey | Child | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | A |  |
| 2 |  | B |  |
| 3 | 1 | C | A |
| 4 | 2 | C | B |
| 5 | Doesn't matter if 3 or 4 | D | C |

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Parent IS NULL THEN NULL 

ELSE 

(SELECT NodeKey from table WHERE Parent IN (SELECT Child from table)) END) as ParentKey
```

When executing this code it tells me that "Subquery returned more that 1 value" which makes sense. But regardless where I put a `max()` or `min()` it doesn't work.

When I put `max()`
in front of NodeKey it just returns a column full with NULL and 105314. 105314 is the amount of rows in the table.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not matter what ParentKey will be used, you can use MIN (MAX) function:

```
SELECT 
    TBL.NodeKey,
    PK AS ParentKey,
    TBL.Child, 
    TBL.Parent
FROM TBL
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Child, MIN(NodeKey) PK FROM TBL GROUP BY Child
) P ON P.Child = TBL.Parent;
```

[Test MS SQL query](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=ceb93b27639c8faba6cedd8984eac2dc&php_version=null&sql_version=mssql2019)

or another version:

```
SELECT 
    TBL.NodeKey,
    MIN(P.NodeKey) AS ParentKey,
    TBL.Child, 
    TBL.Parent
FROM TBL
LEFT JOIN TBL P ON P.Child = TBL.Parent
GROUP BY TBL.NodeKey, TBL.Child, TBL.Parent;
```

Result:

```
+=========+===========+=======+========+
| NodeKey | ParentKey | Child | Parent |
+=========+===========+=======+========+
| 1       | (null)    | A     | (null) |
+---------+-----------+-------+--------+
| 2       | (null)    | B     | (null) |
+---------+-----------+-------+--------+
| 3       | 1         | C     | A      |
+---------+-----------+-------+--------+
| 4       | 2         | C     | B      |
+---------+-----------+-------+--------+
| 5       | 3         | D     | C      |
+---------+-----------+-------+--------+
```